# SQL*Plus issues with connection to DB from Command Prompt

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am on SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0, on a Windows machine.

In the command prompt, when I do

> C:\users\TOMMY> sqlplus /nolog

I see this

> SQL>

Here I connect to the Database using a connection string(EZ Connect format)

With Credentials,

username -> dddd

pwd -> wefm@vrev

host -> local

port -> 15210

ServiceName -> abcd.xysp.gthe.com

> SQL> connect dddd/"wefm@vrev"@local:15210/abcd.xysp.gthe.com

And I see Output(after a few seconds),

> Connected.

My issue begins when I decide to connect from Windows directly with sqlplus. Mentioned below

> C:\users\TOMMY> sqlplus -S
> dddd/"wefm@vrev"@local:15210/abcd.xysp.gthe.com

Results in an error, I am baffled. What am I missing

> ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
> specified

I have also tried putting the connection string in single quotes (').
When I do that I get this whole thing printed out, which I assume is indicative of me passing the wrong args.

> SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.
>
> Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V
>
> ```
> -H             Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
>                usage help.
> -V             Displays the SQL*Plus version.
> ```
>
> Usage 2: sqlplus [ [] [{logon | /nolog}] [] ]
>
> is: [-C ] [-F] [-L] [-M ""]
> [-NOLOGINTIME]
>                [-R ] [-S]
>
> ```
> -C <version>   Sets the compatibility of affected commands to the
>                version specified by <version>.  The version has
>                the form "x.y[.z]".  For example, -C 10.2.0
> -F             This option improves performance in general. It changes
>                the default values settings.
>                See SQL*Plus User's Guide for the detailed settings.
> -L             Attempts to log on just once, instead of
>                prompting on error.
> -M "<options>" Sets automatic HTML or CSV markup of output.  The options
>                have the form:
>                {HTML html_options|CSV csv_options}
>                See SQL*Plus User's Guide for detailed HTML and CSV options.
> -NOLOGINTIME   Don't display Last Successful Login Time.
> -R <level>     Sets restricted mode to disable SQL*Plus commands
>                that interact with the file system.  The level can
>                be 1, 2 or 3.  The most restrictive is -R 3 which
>                disables all user commands interacting with the
>                file system.
> -S             Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
>                the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
>                commands.
> ```
>
> is: {[/][@<connect_identifier>] | / }
> [AS {SYSDBA | SYSOPER | SYSASM | SYSBACKUP | SYSDG
> | SYSKM | SYSRAC}] [EDITION=value]
>
> ```
> Specifies the database account username, password and connect
> identifier for the database connection.  Without a connect
> identifier, SQL*Plus connects to the default database.
>
> The AS SYSDBA, AS SYSOPER, AS SYSASM, AS SYSBACKUP, AS SYSDG,
> AS SYSKM and AS SYSRAC options are database administration privileges.
>
> <connect_identifier> can be in the form of Net Service Name
> or Easy Connect.
>
>   @[<net_service_name> | [[//]Host[:Port]/<service_name>] |
>     [[[protocol:]//]host1{,host12}[:port1]{,host2:port2}[/service_name]
>      [:server][/instance name][?[parameter name=value]
>      {&parameter name=value}]]]
>
>     <net_service_name> is a simple name for a service that resolves
>     to a connect descriptor.
>
>     Example: Connect to database using Net Service Name and the
>              database net service name is ORCL.
>
>        sqlplus username/mypassword@ORCL
>
>     Host specifies the host name or IP address of the database
>     server computer.
>
>     Port specifies the listening port on the database server.
>
>     <service name> specifies the service name of the database you
>     want to access.
>
>     Example: Connect to database using Easy Connect and the
>              Service name is ORCL.
>
>        sqlplus username/mypassword@Host/ORCL
>
> The /NOLOG option starts SQL*Plus without connecting to a
> database.
>
> The EDITION specifies the value for Session Edition.
> ```
>
> is: @|[.] [ ...]
>
> ```
> Runs the specified SQL*Plus script from a web server (URL) or the
> local file system (filename.ext) with specified parameters that
> will be assigned to substitution variables in the script.
> ```
>
> When SQL*Plus starts, and after CONNECT commands, the site profile
> (e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) and the user profile
> (e.g. login.sql in the working directory) are run.  The files may
> contain SQL*Plus commands.
>
> Refer to the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference for more information.

I would like a solution that only involves using a connection string. I don't want to be using tns_ora file
Also without any manual intervention. I don't want to separately enter the password after I put in 'username@connect-identifier'.

Please ignore security related issues of passing in the password visibly in the cmd prompt. That is fine with me.

Comment: There are a variety of issues with special characters in the password when placed in the command line, depending on the OS or shell in play. It is not always possible to work around them. The only special character that works universally is the underscore `_`. The `@` in particular is hard to use on the command line because it has special meaning to Oracle internally and can't always be escaped or placed in quotes. In my experience (and I've been at this for almost 30 years) you either need to use a different special character or provide the password in a separate prompt (not on the CL).

Answer (score 1):

Solution powershell script test-connect2.ps1:

```
$username = "demin"
$password = '"test@test"'
$connect_string ="10.241.33.71:1521/DEV"
$log_file = "log.txt"

$list_scripts = "connect $username/$password@$connect_string"
$list_scripts = $list_scripts + " 
select 1,sysdate from dual;
@file1.sql
@file2.sql"
$list_scripts | sqlplus -s /nolog  >>$log_file
```

Run script:

```
C:\instantclient_21_3>powershell .\test-connect2.ps1
```

output log.txt

```
     1 SYSDATE
---------- ---------
     1 27-MAY-22


     2 SYSDATE
---------- ---------
     2 27-MAY-22


     3 SYSDATE
---------- ---------
     3 27-MAY-22


SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri May 27 06:34:41 2022
    
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
    
SQL> alter user DEMIN identified by "test@test";
User altered.
SQL> exit    
    
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
    
C:\>sqlplus demin/"test@test"@dev19
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri May 27 06:35:14 2022
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
Enter user-name:
    
C:\>sqlplus demin/\"test@test\"@dev19
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri May 27 06:35:23 2022
           
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
            
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
            
SQL> show user
USER is "DEMIN"
SQL>

C:\app\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin>sqlplus demin/\"test@test\"@dev19                                                                                                                                               
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 27 10:28:18 2022
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri May 27 2022 06:35:29 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.12.0.0.0

SQL>

C:\instantclient_19_15>sqlplus demin/\"test@test\"@dev19                                                                                                                                                           
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 27 11:23:35 2022
Version 19.15.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri May 27 2022 10:31:49 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.12.0.0.0

SQL>


C:\instantclient_21_3>sqlplus demin/\"test@test\"@dev19                                                                                                                                                            
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 27 11:18:08 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0
    
Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in the SQL*Plus version that I have specified. Release 21.0.0.0.0 . When I try the exact above I get this --> ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor

Comment: You can install oracle instant client 19 and sqlplus 19 and connect to database. Instant client is very small about 200kb.

Comment: You can use simple powershell script. I updated answer.